# Unable to run Swagger when running Web API with virtual directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, swagger, owin

I'm currently working on some API documentation using Swagger and Swashbuckle in .Net Standard and ASP.Net.

Navigating to ../swagger/ui/index results in a 404 when running my Web API in LocalIIS with a virtual directory.

Performing the above steps when running the Web API in IISExpress results in the Swagger UI page being displayed as expected.

I've looked through Google for similar issues, however most of these still result in the Swagger UI page being shown, but the URL itself is not resolved to the correct one. I can't even get that far as I get a 404 as soon as I try to navigate to the Swagger UI Index.html.

The closest description I could find to my problem was here:

https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/305

I implemented the fix suggested by StanislavKuzymkiv on this article but it didn't resolve my issue.

As part of the virtual directory set up, are there any swagger files that I have to manually copy across that I could have missed?

I'm also using https rather than http if that makes any difference to the set up

Below is a snippet of my SwaggerConfig file with the RootUrl 'fix'.

```
        httpConfiguration.EnableSwagger(c =>
        {
            c.MultipleApiVersions(
                (apiDesc, targetApiVersion) => ResolveVersionSupportByRouteConstraint(apiDesc, targetApiVersion),
                (vc) =>
                {
                    vc.Version("v2", "Open API V2");
                    vc.Version("v1", "Open API V1");
                });

            c.RootUrl(req => { var pathBase = req.GetOwinContext().Get<string>("owin.RequestPathBase"); return new Uri(req.RequestUri, pathBase).ToString(); });
            c.Schemes(new[] { "https" });
```

Comment: Hi, did you ever come right with this?

Comment: facing the same.